# Using Google sheet script to push data from HTML form to sheet not working when sheet is not open

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a Google App script to send data from an HTML form to a Google spreadsheet. This works perfectly when I have the spreadsheet open in my browser; the data I put in the form is submitted to the sheet. On the other hand, when I close the spreadsheet and fill out the form, noting is submitted to the sheet.

[Here is my script.](https://gist.github.com/Sade66/0a5ceade48a29d8915880f44384ad1b6)

```
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: Is your script an standalone script or a bounded to a spreadsheet? Please note that as it could be useful to share a file with the complete code, questions should be self contained so it's suggested to include a [mcve] within the question.

Comment: @Rubén the script is bound to a Spreadsheet. As I said, the data is submitted to the sheet when I have the sheet open, but does not go to the sheet when I don't have it open. Would it be helpful if I attach my html code as well?

Comment: I recommend that you embed your sample code into this question, so that when a resolution is recommended the page will contain the entire Q&A.

Comment: @terrywb I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14330297/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there is no "active spreadsheet" when you have the spreadsheet closed.

```
function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

I recommend that you hardcode the spreadsheet id into your code.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I'm new to Google scripts.

Comment: The value returned by doc.getId() is also visible in the URL when your spreadsheet is open.  Just replace doc.getId() with that value.